# Express generator with socket.io configuration

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Below code is my current configuration, it worked but I'm confused.

server side

```
var server = require("http").Server(express);  
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
server.listen(5000);
io.on('connection', function(client) {


});
```

cilent

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
```

**Why we need to create another server for socket at port 5000 for an application**? can't socket use 3000? which is the express's running port. I removed the line of server.listen('5000') and do server.listen() and try connect to port 3000 at client side it doesn't work.

Comment: You can use the same port for your web server as for socket.io as you are doing in the code you show (on port 5000).  If you want help with the code that doesn't work, you need to show us that code.   `server.listen(5000);` is starting your express server.  You have to put a port there.  `var io = require("socket.io")(server);` is binding socket.io to your web server.   `var server = require("http").Server(express);  ` is creating a web server and binding the express request handler to it.

Comment: @jfriend00 the new express version create server in bin/www, I remove the create server lines and it work now.

Comment: Since you don't show us anything that could help us actually answer your question or help anyone that comes after and you now appear to have things figured out, maybe you should just delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

By default express 4 create a server and run it bin/www. I solved this issue by commenting out `server.listen(port);` in that file.